# SPListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion creates minor version?

Tags: sharepoint

In a document library in which minor version is enabled, UpdateOverwriteVersion() creates a minor version.

The thread - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/e0d1af63-3705-4b58-95c5-f0f92f86a23f - explains the similar problem and proposes the solution as turn-off the minor versioning, update the item and turn-on the minor versioning.

But, I cannot temporarily turn-off the minor versioning setting, since the same library may be in use by other users to upload/change their documents and the turning-off the setting might affect their operations.

Is there any-other solution?

Thanks and Regards,

Arjabh

Answer (score 1):

```
If the goal is to update the fields without creating multiple versions see the code:

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File lp_newFile = lp_web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(lp_uri.LocalPath);
lp_context.Load(lp_newFile);
lp_context.ExecuteQuery();

//check out to make sure not to create multiple versions
lp_newFile.CheckOut();

ListItem lp_item = lp_newFile.ListItemAllFields;
listItem["Created"] = info.SourceFile.CreationTime;
listItem["Modified"] = info.SourceFile.LastWriteTime;
listItem.Update();

// use OverwriteCheckIn type to make sure not to create multiple versions 
lp_newFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
```

Comment: CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn doesn't work for me. It creates new minor version anyway. At least with SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Try listItem.SystemUpdate(false) instead of listItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()

Comment: This works, but has a little drawback for me. It appends changes made the last existing version in version history, which can be quite confusing..

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this (it works for me) :

```
//Disable minor versions on your list or library, if your item is in a major version (maybe use a file.Publish before)
list.EnableMinorVersions = false;
list.Update();

//Update item and overwrite your major version
ListItem lp_item = lp_newFile.ListItemAllFields;
lp_item["Created"] = info.SourceFile.CreationTime;
lp_item["Modified"] = info.SourceFile.LastWriteTime;
lp_item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();

//Enable minor versions
list.EnableMinorVersions = true;
list.Update();
```